# How to Change the Json format?

Tags: jquery, json

i am getting the JSON format as below

```
[{
    "year": "2015-01-05",
    "contentTitle": "bus",
    "aid": 43050500
}, {
    "year": "2015-01-14",
    "contentTitle": "paratransit",
    "aid": 1435400
}]
```

But i need format as below

```
[
  {
    "year": "2015-01-05",
    "bus": 43050500,
    "paratransit": 1435400,
    "rail": 174436000
  },
  {
    "year": "2015-01-14",
    "bus": 420572700,
    "paratransit": 1924800,
    "rail": 168658800
  }]
```

I tried some extent to archive by using the following

```
data.forEach(function (d) { 

    var gameName = d.contentTitle;  
     var gameValue = d.aid; 
        d[gameName] = gameValue;
        d.year = parseformat(d.year);
        delete d["contentTitle"];
        delete d["aid"];


    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

But i did't get as expected.

Comment: Neither of your examples are valid json.

Comment: while copying code error is occured ...both json data is valid

Comment: At least [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36644324/edit) with the proper code.

Answer (score 0):

you should `map` your array instead of `forEach`

```js
data = [{
  year: "2015-01-05",
  contentTitle: "bus",
  "aid": 43050500
}, {
  year: "2015-01-14",
  contentTitle: "paratransit",
  aid: 1435400
}];

data = data.map(function (d) {
    d[d.contentTitle] = d.aid;
    d.year = d.year; // parseformat me <<
    delete d["contentTitle"];
    delete d["aid"];

    return d;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank kiro for you reply... But the data format is not as i expected can you have look on that